# Is there anything wrong with my code my var_dump is throwing null on line 88 but line 57 took data and saved data to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website which has series of registration process and at last it gives OTP code and after sucessfull process it says registration sucessfull and user need to click login tab and then he needs to login.

but what i'm tryying to do is auto login after sucessfull registration.

i tried this

```
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$name;
```

it didn't worked and when i did this

```
    var_dump($_SESSION['login_user']);
```

it gave me null

**note: $name is $_POST['name']; **

but on line 57 $name data got saved into database and in line 87 it's showing null

sorry for my bad english hope you guys understand what i mean

**ps i know the code is vunerable to SQL injection of working on that too**

**code for registration process **

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('../connection.php');
require "../PHPmailer/mail_function.php";
$success = "";
$error_message = "";
$error_message1 ="";
$error_message2="";
$success1="";
$success2="";
$name= $_POST['name'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
              
     
      $count=0;
      $a= $b=$c=$d=$e = "";
      $a = $_POST['password1'];
      $b= $_POST['password2'];
      $c= $_POST['password3'];
      $d= $_POST['password4'];
      $e= $_POST['password5'];
      $f = $a.$b.$c.$d.$e;
      $res=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `logincode` WHERE Id ='$f';");
      
      $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
      $count=mysqli_num_rows($res);

      if($count==0)
      {
        $error_message ="ID Doesn't Match!";
        echo $f;
      }
      else
        $success = "Now Register!";
      }
      
if(!empty($_POST["submit_email"])) {
  $count=0;

        $sql="SELECT name,email from registration";
        $res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
          
          if ($row['email']==$_POST['email']){
            if($row['name']==$_POST['name']){
            $count = $count +1;

          }
        }
      }
        if($count==0)
        {
          $name= $_POST['name'];
          $email=$_POST['email'];
          $phone =$_POST['phone'];
          $sql = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO registration(name,email,phone) VALUES('$name', '$email', '$phone')");
          
          
          $otp = rand(100000,999999);
    // Send OTP
    
    $mail_status = sendOTP($_POST["email"],$otp);
    
    if($mail_status == 1) {
      $result = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO otp_expiry(otp,is_expired,create_at) VALUES ('" . $otp . "', 1, '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). "')");
      $current_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
      if(!empty($current_id)) {
        $success1= "Enter Email OTP For registration ";
      }
    }
  } else {
   
   $error_message1 ='First Register As Valid User in Eat Gita';
  }
}
if(!empty($_POST["submit_otp"])) {
  $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM otp_expiry WHERE otp='" . $_POST["otp"] . "' AND is_expired=1 AND NOW() <= DATE_ADD(create_at, INTERVAL 24 HOUR)");
  $count  = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if(!empty($count)) {
    $result = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE otp_expiry SET is_expired = 0 WHERE otp = '" . $_POST["otp"] . "'");
    $success1 = "registration success Now Login!"; 
  
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$name;
    var_dump($_SESSION['login_user']);
    
    
        

  } else {
    
    $error_message2 = "Invalid OTP!";
  } 
}
?>
```

Comment: it might be better to create a `login` function by passing the `id` of the user instead of using `name`. of course, you can compare the `id` and `name` and all other security check before jumping to login

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? That's a lot of code, which parts are working as expected, which are not?

Answer (score 0):

Of your whole php, the lines 80 through 97 runs after submitting with **submit_otp** filled. Check if you are submitting values for **name** too while submitting **submit_otp**.

Simply print $name in line 86 to check if name has value.